# DropDownList remains empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have searched a lot and I'm not able to pinpoint where the issue is, it returns an empty DropDownList with the "Seleccione Rol" text, so I guess the problem is that the DDL isn't getting populated, I really appreciate any help.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Usuario_rol()
{
    using (proyectob_dbEntities db = new proyectob_dbEntities())
    {
        usuario_rol model = new usuario_rol();
        model.rolesList = db.roles;

        //roles model2 = new roles();
        //model.roles.rolesl = db.roles;
    }
    return View(new usuario_rol());           
}
```

**The view:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.roles, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.id_rol, new SelectList(Model.rolesList, "id", "rol"),"Seleccione Rol")
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Model:**

```
public partial class usuario_rol
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string id_usuario { get; set; }
    public string id_rol { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime fecha_inicio_rel { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime fecha_termino_rel { get; set; }

    public virtual contactos contactos { get; set; }
    public virtual roles roles { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<roles> rolesList { get; set; }

    public usuario_rol()
    {
        rolesList = new List<roles>();
    }
```

**the DB:**

[image: the DB looks like this]

Comment: Your just returning a new instance of the model, not the one you populated with data. `return View(model);` (but delete you `using` block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not sending model to view, you are passing new object, which is empty, to view.

Change `return View(new usuario_rol());` with this `return View(model);`

Comment: Thank you very much, I put the `usuario_rol model = new usuario_rol();` outside the using and now it works, then I added ToList() in  `model.rolesList = db.roles.ToList();` cause it gave an error of "DbContext has been disposed", thank you CodeNotFound too (don't know why your answer got deleted, though)

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work:

Context :

```
public class RoleContext  
{  
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYConnector"].ToString());  
    public IEnumerable<RoleTable> GetRoleList()  
    {  
        // it would be good if you put inline query in procedure
        string query = "SELECT RoleName,RoleId FROM RoleTable";  
        var result = con.Query<RoleTable>(query);  
        return result;  
   }  
}
```

ActionMethod:

```
public ActionResult Usuario_rol()
{
    RoleContext roleList = new RoleContext();
    usuario_rol model = new usuario_rol();
    using (proyectob_dbEntities db = new proyectob_dbEntities())
    {
        model.rolesList = new SelectList(roleList.GetRoleList(),"RoleName","RoleId");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

And the view :

```
@namespace of the model
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.roles, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-5">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.id_rol, model.rolesList ,"Seleccione Rol")
</div>
```